# Create new variable for a group of records in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with the first 4 columns and I want to create the last column. My dataset has millions of records.

| ID | Date | Code | Event of Interest | *Want to Create* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 101 | * | 201 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 201 | yes | 201 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 301 | * | 201 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 401 | * | 201 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 101 | * | 301 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 201 | * | 301 |
| 2 | 1/5/2022 | 301 | yes | 301 |

I want to group records by ID and date. If one of the records in the grouping has a 'yes' in the event of interest variable, I want to assign that code to the entire grouping. I am using base SAS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will only have one `yes` value for each id and date, you can use a lookup table and merge them together. Here are a few ways to do it.

**1. Self-merge**

Simply merge the data onto itself where `event = yes`.

```
data want;
    merge have
          have(rename=(code  = new_code
                       event = _event_) 
               where =(upcase(_event_) = 'YES')
              )
    ;
    by id date;
    
    drop _event_;
run;
```

**2. SQL Self-join**

Same as above, but using a SQL inner join.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.*
             , t2.code as new_code
        from have as t1
        INNER JOIN
             have as t2
        ON     t1.id = t2.id
           AND t1.date = t2.date
        where upcase(t2.event) = 'YES'
    ;
quit;
```

**3. Hash lookup table**

This is more advanced but can be quite performant if you have the memory. Notice that it looks very similar to our `merge` statement in Option 1. We're creating a lookup table, loading it to memory, and using a hash join to pull values from that in-memory table. `h.Find()` will check the unique combination of (`id`, `date`) in the value read from the `set` statement against the hash table in memory. If a match is found, it will pull the value of `new_code`.

```
data want;
    set have;

    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        dcl hash h(dataset: "have(rename=(code= new_code) 
                                  where =(upcase(event) = 'YES')
                                 )"
                 , hashexp:20);
            h.defineKey('id', 'date');
            h.defineData('new_code');
        h.defineDone();

        call missing(new_code);
    end;

    rc = h.Find();

    drop rc;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested out the solution that seemed the most straightforward, the self-merge, and it seems to have worked as expected. There may be cases where there is more than one 'yes' per ID/date combination but I have not run into any yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remember the last value of CODE you want for the group by using a double [DOW loop](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/052-2012.pdf).

In the first loop copy the code value to the new variable. The second loop can re-read the observations and write them out with the extra variable filled in.

```
data want;
  do until (last.date);
    set have;
    by id date ;
    if 'Event of Interest'n='yes' then 'Want to Create'n=code;
  end;
  do until (last.date);
    set have;
    by id date;
    output;
  end;
run;
```